SSLCertVerificationError when run a lambda aws python code inside localstack trying to connect to a mockserver inside docker
I'm trying to test the code of a lambda function(AWS) with python code running locally inside localstack, I create a mock server that should return the HTTPS request, but I'm getting:
SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain.
It's not possible to change the python code, however, I'm able to set the cert_data_file_name, pk_file_name and authorization_header.
The function has this code:
return HTTPSConnectionPool(
    host=host_addr,
    cert_reqs="CERT_REQUIRED",
    cert_file=cert_data_file_name,
    key_file=pk_file_name,
    headers={"Authorization": authorization_header},
    timeout=Timeout(connect=int(connect_timeout), read=int(read_timeout)))

docker-compose.yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
    mockServer:
        image: mockserver/mockserver:5.15.0
    ports:
        - 443:443
    environment:
        MOCKSERVER_SERVER_PORT: 443
        MOCKSERVER_TLS: true

These are the things I've tried and it doesn't work:

To set the cert_data_file_name and pk_file_name content equals to CertificateAuthorityCertificate and PKCS8CertificateAuthorityPrivateKey.
Set environment variables to avoid CA verification,
CURL_CA_BUNDLE=""
REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=""
PYTHONHTTPSVERIFY=0

If I set the cert_reqs="CERT_NONE", the code run perfectly

"These are the things I've tried and it doesn't work: ... 3. If I set the cert_reqs="CERT_NONE", the code run perfectly" - based on this #3 works ("the code run perfectly"),  then why you claim it does not ("I've tried and doesn't work"). In any case: cert_file and key_file are unrelated to server certificates validation, they are about client certificates. PYTHONHTTPSVERIFY seems to be some Jenkins specific thing and does not apply to HTTPSConnectionPool in general. You seem to use a self-signed certificate which is not trusted - that's exactly what it complains about.

I just updated. Even if I add the self-signed certificate in the client request container with the update-ca-certificates command? I'm sorry if I'm talking nonsense.

The relevant arguments to for HTTPSConnectionPool to specify trusted CA certs are ca_certs and ca_certs_dir - see the documentation. A common error is that the self-signed certificate is not a CA certificate, in which case these arguments don't help. HTTPSConnectionPool does not provide a way to treat a non-CA certificate as trust anchor.
